# Is corse parent == parent index?

Tags: geospatial, h3

In the H3 library, you can find the corse parent index of a H3 hexagon using the [`h3ToParent` method](https://uber.github.io/h3/#/documentation/api-reference/hierarchy). Is the corse parent the same as the parent? If not how do I find the true parent index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The H3 docs generally use "coarse" to indicate larger-hex resolutions with lower numbers (e.g. res 1 hexes, 607,220km2), and "fine" to indicate smaller-hex resolutions with higher numbers (e.g. res 10 hexes, 0.015km2). This is to avoid confusion with "bigger"/"smaller" terminology (is a bigger resolution a large hex or a larger res number?).

The `h3ToParent` method can return the direct parent of a hexagon (i.e. the coarser hexagon that contains it at the next resolution up), or its ancestor at any given coarser resolution - the second argument specifies the resolution of the parent you want to obtain.

[image]

In this image, for example, all of the larger hexagons are "parents" of the smallest hexagon in the center. If the resolution of the center hex is `7`, then:

```
H3Index directParent = h3ToParent(centerHex, 6);
H3Index grandParent = h3ToParent(centerHex, 5);
// etc
```